# Django CreateView gives an error "needs to have a value for field "..." before this many-to-many relationship can be used."

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm practicing with Django's FormViews.

In this app, I'm creating a PostCreate view that creates a blog post.

Here are my codes:

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_content = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post_title = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Title',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':64})
    )
    post_content = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Content',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':128})
    )
    tags = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Tags',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':64})
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('user', 'post_date')
```

**views.py**

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'app_blog/post_save_form.html'
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user

        tag_names = form.cleaned_data['tags'].split()
        for tag_name in tag_names:
            tag, dummy = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
            self.object.tag_set.add(tag)

        return super(PostCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

When I try saving a post (Test Post 1) into a database, it gives me an error:

**needs to have a value for field "post" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.**

It looks like the problem is caused by lines in views.py where I split the "tag" field and add the tags to the post object's tag_set field. I suppose this logic should not be included in the form_valid method... but I don't know where else this should be implemented..

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks

Answer (score 9):

No, that's not what the problem is. The problem is that you haven't saved the Post object yet, so you can't create a many-to-many relationship with it (because under the hood, m2m is just a linking table with foreign keys to both entities). The solution is to save `self.object` first.

Comment: Your suggestion solved the error!! However, after doing that, Tag object is added for EVERY post for some reason.... For example, if I add Tag1 to Post#4, Tag1 is added to Post#1,Post#2,Post#3,and Post#4.. Idk why this is happening... :(

Comment: Yes. The hint really helps. By the way, sometimes I think good error messages are green. Bad (confusing) error messages (like this one) need to think to google to ask (and also to be answered). Maybe even worse, if questioner does not know to accept a correct answer ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You should save your object after assigning user and then do things with m2m relations:

```
self.object = form.save(commit=False)  # Not saved to database.
self.object.user = self.request.user
self.object.save()  # Saved.

tag_names = form.cleaned_data['tags'].split()
for tag_name in tag_names:
    tag, dummy = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
    self.object.tag_set.add(tag)
```